# Free jqGrid 4.9.0 - combine multiboxonly with setSelection

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/mrfvsyc2/12/`enter code here`

When I'm using the multiboxonly, I have to click within the actual checkbox, in order to select multiple rows.  If I only select a row, it will reset all my other selections.  That's the desired behavior I need, which works OK.

The problem is with the setSelection method (grid.setSelection), which "act" as if I'm clicking within the checkbox, while I need it to act as if I'm clicking on the row.

In the demo, I'm using the setSelection each time user do a right click on a row.  I need the selection to act as if the user only clicked on the row, and not as if the user checked the checkbox.

Can the setColumn function take into account the multiboxonly option?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understand correctly which selection behavior you want to implement, but it seems to me that you need just change the line

```
$('#jqGrid').setSelection(rowId);
```

inside of `onContextMenu` to two lines:

```
$('#jqGrid').resetSelection();
$('#jqGrid').setSelection(rowId);
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/mrfvsyc2/13/